# Repeating Tests in Multiple Contexts with Shoulda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shoulda

I run into this issue a lot and haven't figured out the best and most beautiful way to avoid repeating complicated code. Here is the problem I have the exact same tests that I want to run in multiple contexts. What is the best way to handle this?

```
context 'first context' do
   setup do
      # Setup
   end

   should 'do something' do
     ...
   end

   should 'do something else' do
     ...
   end
end

context 'second context' do
   setup do
      # Different setup
   end

   should 'do something' do
     ...
   end

   should 'do something else' do
     ...
   end
end
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a good canonical post on `shared_examples` but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: @FrederickCheung Let me know if you find a good example. I haven't found any?

Comment: Well I'd start by reading the docs for `shared_examples`

Comment: @FrederickCheung do you have a link of what you are talking about?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm not using rspec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115537/discussion-between-tom-rossi-and-frederick-cheung).

Comment: Whoops - looked a lot like rspec - my mistake